# Unusual behavior in symfony2/doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following problem:

I want to check something before saving the object in the database:

here my controller:

```
/**
 * Edits an existing Document entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="document_update")
 * @Method("PUT")
 * @Template("ControlBundle:Document:edit.html.twig")
 */
 public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();    
        $entity = $em->getRepository('ControlBundle:Document')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Document entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createForm(new DocumentType(), $entity);
        $editForm->bind($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
           $document = $em->getRepository('ControlBundle:Document')->findOneBy(array(
            'id' => $id,
            ));

           if ($document->getCount() > 100)
              $em->flush();
        }

      return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
     );
  }
```

in my database i have:

```
id   count .......
23    110
```

in my form i edit:

```
id   count .......
23    34
```

but when I do this:

```
$document = $em->getRepository('ControlBundle:Document')->findOneBy(array(
   'id' => $id,
));

//here $document->getCount() return 34; ------WHY? should return 110!!!
if ($document->getCount() > 100)
   $em->flush();
```

best regards :D

Comment: First you bind the `$document` from the request, then you overwriting it with the not yet persisted values from the database. And it isn't already persisted, because you don't flush it at this time. I don't understand why you overwrite the `$document`, you should delete this line `$document = $em->getRepository('ControlBundle:Document')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id,));` and then should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine Entity Manager **is already managing this entity** (Document with ID=23), and it does not re-load data from database the second time, it just uses the entity it's already managing, whose ***count*** value has been replaced by 34 in the form...

Try this :

```
 /**
  * Edits an existing Document entity.
  *
  * @Route("/{id}", name="document_update")
  * @Method("PUT")
  * @Template("ControlBundle:Document:edit.html.twig")
  */
 public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();    
    $entity = $em->getRepository('ControlBundle:Document')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Document entity.');
    }

    $lastCountValue = $entity->getCount();

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createForm(new DocumentType(), $entity);
    $editForm->bind($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid() && lastCountValue > 100) {
        $em->flush();
    }

  return array(
    'entity' => $entity,
    'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
    'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
 );
```

}